# ng5-slider catch on focus event

Tags: angular, datepicker, slider

I'm using Angular 8 and ng5-slider. I was wondering if there is any way to catch on slider focus event.

What I need to create:

On focus on the minValue/maxValue point (on the slider), I want to show a date-picker.

app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Options, PointerType } from 'ng5-slider';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-trigger-focus-slider',
  templateUrl: './trigger-focus-slider.component.html'
})
export class TriggerFocusSliderComponent {
  triggerFocus: EventEmitter<PointerType> = new EventEmitter<PointerType>();
  minValue: number = 20;
  maxValue: number = 80;
  options: Options = {
    floor: 0,
    ceil: 100,
    step: 5
  };

  PointerType: any = PointerType;

  focusSlider(pointerType: PointerType): void {
    this.triggerFocus.emit(pointerType);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="focusSlider(PointerType.Min)">Focus min pointer</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="focusSlider(PointerType.Max)">Focus max pointer</button>
</p>

<ng5-slider [(value)]="minValue" [(highValue)]="maxValue" [options]="options" [triggerFocus]="triggerFocus"></ng5-slider>
```

*Disclaimer*

I'm new in Angular

Comment: you have to show a datepicker when the slider reach maxValue or minValue right?

Comment: @reaghul-selvam no. I need to show the date picker as soon as the user clicks on the slider (either minValue or maxValue)